# How to invite participant to an existing call in MS teams using API?

Tags: api, web-applications, postman, integration, microsoft-teams

I am trying to invite participants to an existing Teams meeting Using API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#invite-a-participant-to-an-existing-call

I am referring this above link to call API. I don't know how to get call ID.
Kindly explain how to hit in postman to get response. Also provide some other reference link to invite participant to an existing call.

Edited:

I am receiving response as "unknown error".
[image: my response]

I have given my authorization token as admin access token.

Kindly explain how to get "replacesCallId","id" and "clientContext" for post method.

kindly give solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call ID can be obtained in two ways:

i. Navigate to Office365 > Admin > Teams > Users > Manage users > search for a user > Meetings & calls

https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/calls-session/ed8e119a-199d-4948-b75d-f1def49a5056

ii. Create a [callRecord subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

O365 sends HTTP POST to your endpoint each time a call is completed. The payload will contain the call id.

2. This following doc explains how to use postman for calling graph API.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman#:~:text=%20Use%20Postman%20with%20the%20Microsoft%20Graph%20API,environment%20variables%20used%20to%20retrieve%20an...%20More%20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman#:%7E:text=%20Use%20Postman%20with%20the%20Microsoft%20Graph%20API,environment%20variables%20used%20to%20retrieve%20an...%20More%20)

Attaching screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question please checkout. I having error like unknown error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194099/how-to-invite-participant-to-an-existing-call-in-ms-teams-using-api

Comment: replacesCallId : `Optional. The call which the target identity is currently a part of. This call will be dropped once the participant is added.`  and clientContext: `Unique Client Context string. Max limit is 256 chars.`